# SQL Server group pivot table according to id

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table called 'info':

```
|InfoId   | OtherId | Year | InfoNo |
-------------------------------------
|1        | 1       | 2012 | abc    |
|2        | 1       | 2013 | def    |
|3        | 1       | 2014 | ghi    |
```

I want to get this result:

```
| OtherId   | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
---------------------------------
|   1       | abc  | def  | ghi  |
```

i tried using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM info
PIVOT (MAX(InfoNo) 
       FOR Year in ([2012],[2013],[2014])) AS pvt
       where OtherId= '1'
```

But instead, I get this result:

```
| OtherId   | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
---------------------------------
|   1       | abc  |       |     |
|   1       |      | def   |     |
|   1       |      |       | ghi |
```

How do I make the three rows group as one row according to 'OtherId'?

**EDIT**

I updated my SQL to the following and manage to get the result I wanted as well:

```
SELECT 
OtherId,
MAX(case WHEN Year = '2012' THEN InvoiceNo ELSE NULL end) AS [2012],
MAX(case WHEN Year = '2013' THEN InvoiceNo ELSE NULL end) AS [2013],
MAX(case WHEN Year = '2014' THEN InvoiceNo ELSE NULL end) AS [2014]
FROM info
```

Thanks all for helping me.

Comment: Hi @newguy42 i wriitten code using Dynamic sql it will be usefull to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your result by `OtherId`, I did a quick test and here's the result:

```
Select * FROM info

InfoId      OtherId     Year        InfoNo
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           2012        abc       
2           1           2013        edf       
3           1           2014        ghk
```

---

```
SELECT 
    pvt.OtherId, 
    MAX([2012]) AS '2012', 
    MAX([2013]) AS '2013', 
    MAX([2014]) AS '2014' 
FROM info AS src
PIVOT (
    MAX(InfoNo) 
    FOR [Year] IN ([2012],[2013],[2014])) 
    AS pvt
GROUP BY pvt.OtherId

Result:
OtherId     2012       2013       2014
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           abc        edf        ghk
```

Hope that helps your cause.

Comment: Wow this works! Thank you very much, but I apologize because I cannot upvote your answer because I am new here.

Comment: The idea is not about getting upvote, we're all around here to help each other in my opinion. Glad I was able to help you. I suggest reading a little bit more about Group By and Pivot

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOt NUll
Drop Table #Temp

;With cte(InfoId ,OtherId ,[Year],InfoNo)
AS
(
SELECT 1,1,'2012' , 'abc' Union all
SELECT 2,1,'2013' , 'def'   Union all
SELECT 3,1,'2014' , 'ghi'
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM cte


DECLARE @dynamicCol nvarchar(max),@dynamicCol2 nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @dynamicCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(Year)  FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @dynamicCol2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + 'MAX('+ QUOTENAME(Year) +' )' +'  AS '+ QUOTENAME(Year)  FROM  #Temp
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')



SET @Sql= N' SELECT [OtherId] , '+ @dynamicCol2 +' From
             (
                SELECT InfoId ,OtherId ,[Year],InfoNo From
                #temp
              )AS Src
                PIVOT 
                    (
                    MAX([InfoNo]) For [Year] IN ('+@dynamicCol+')
                    )
            AS Pvt
            GROUP BY Pvt.OtherId
            '

PRINT @Sql

EXEC(@Sql)
```

OutPut

```
| OtherId   | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 |
---------------------------------
|   1       | abc  | def  | ghi  |
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. It took me awhile to understand this and I'm glad because I learn something new from you. Thank you.